# quickblox group chat in Android

Tags: quickblox

Can I create a group chat based on interests? For example in my first activity I want to list some interests such as sports, music, art etc... And user clicks one of them and joins a group chat(could be also a chat-room) to chat other users with same interest. Is this possible with quickblox? Can I use custom parameters for this purpose? http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Custom_parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yeah quickblox offers public group chat feature.